# Use fontawesome as checkbox for table rows

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, font-awesome

I have a table with a checkbox for each row. I am using Bootstrap 3 for my table and Font Awesome icons for my check box.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><i type="checkbox" class="icon-check-empty" id="selectall"></i></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><i type="checkbox" class="icon-check-empty option"></i></td>
            <td><a href="#">Anna</a></td>
            <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i type="checkbox" class="icon-check-empty option"></i></td>
            <td><a href="#">John</a></td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the code that enables me to use Font Awesome icons as checkboxes.

```
$('i').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('icon-check')) {
            $(this).removeClass('icon-check').addClass('icon-check-empty');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('icon-check-empty').addClass('icon-check');
        }
});
```

This code is to enable me to select all checkboxes.

```
$(function () {
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
        $('[class*="option"]').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
    $('[class*="option"]').click(function () {
        if ($('[class*="option"]').length == $('[class*="option"]:checked').length) {
            $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

This^ works fine when I'm not using custom checkboxes. But I really want to use the icons from Font Awesome.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: could you create a fiddle please, with your icons

Comment: Take a look at the answer, I hope I understand correctly your question

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `#selectall` element is clicked and if so check/uncheck all others checks.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('i').not('#selectall').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('icon-check')) {
            $(this).removeClass('icon-check').addClass('icon-check-empty');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('icon-check-empty').addClass('icon-check');
        }
    });

    $("#selectall").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('icon-check')) {
            $('i').removeClass('icon-check').addClass('icon-check-empty');
        } else {
            $('i').removeClass('icon-check-empty').addClass('icon-check');
        }
    });

});
```

Remember to add to your CSS:

```
i {
    display: inline-block
}
```

or any selector will fire events on empty `<i>` tag elements.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/zx4pq/